# Master Page inheriting css of web page

Tags: asp.net, css, styles

[image: image of web page]

The blue top bar is from Master page. It is styled using bootstrap.css file. The webpage is styled using demos.css. Blue top bar is inheriting css style sheet from demos.css. How can i prvent this?

Comment: Don't include demos.css :)

Comment: Yes, dont include demos.css :) Whether it's masterpage or not, when loaded to client, it's just one html document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include demos.css is the most obvious answer but if you must include it for whatever reason,assign an id to your main body and give the body it's own styling. This will override any inherited styles.